# XPath ignore siblings that does not match attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML that looks like the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<properties>
    <property name="Name">Ananth</property>
    <property name="Age">34</property>
    <property name="Gender">Male</property>
    <property name="Description">Blah blah</property>
    100 other properties
</properties>
<properties>
    <property name="Name">Peter</property>
    <property name="Age">10</property>
    <property name="Gender">Male</property>
    <property name="Description">Blah blah</property>
    100 other properties
</properties>
</root>
```

I am trying to get properties that matches only attributes with name & age ignoring other siblings.

```
//Property[@name='Name' or @name='Age']/.. 
//Property[@name='Name' or @name='Age']/parent::properties
```

Doesn't get me what I am looking for.  What would be the best xpath expression that would give me something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<properties>
    <property name="Name">Ananth</property>
    <property name="Age">34</property>
</properties>
<properties>
    <property name="Name">Peter</property>
    <property name="Age">10</property>
</properties>
```

Comment: XPath cannot select that which is not already present in the input XML.  Your targeted `properties` elements do not exist in the input XML.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

By the output you expect, I see you are expecting to get not the original `properties` node, but just the `property` matching nodes, because the original `properties` node has 100 properties, and the expected output `properties` node has just 2.

So you need a double xpath to properly get the expected output:

First:

```
properties/property[@name='Name' or @name='Age']/..
```

Then, for each matched `properties` node, a transformation:

```
property[@name='Name' or @name='Age']
```

(Notice that an Xpath expression would return a *plain list* of zero or more nodes, but not a *tree structure* of nodes, as you may seem to expect).

If it is intended to be part of a XSL stylesheet, the complete stylesheet would be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
<xsl:apply-templates select="properties/property[@name='Name' or @name='Age']/.."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="properties">
<properties>
<xsl:apply-templates select="property[@name='Name' or @name='Age']"/>
</properties>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="property">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update**

If you are only filtering `properties` nodes, your first try should work:

```
//property[@name='Name' or @name='Age']/..
```

Remember only that Xpath (as XML) is *case sensitive*: `property` in your input xml is lowercase, and so must be in the xpath expression.

Comment: I am not trying to make a XSLT. I am just trying to filter the other properties that doesn't match the attributes with xpath, expression.

Comment: I see. Read my update, then.